# Fetch the name of the screen (not webpage) that a user is coming from in a C# Wizard

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am working on a page within a C# desktop application. On this page I have a hyperlink, that resides on FORM A, "Add New" that presents the user with a "New Contact Wizard".

This Wizard is used in different areas of the desktop app. I want to pre-populate fields on the screen depending on which page the user is coming from.

```
if( previousLocation.Name == "FORM A")
      Control.Value == "Conditional Value"
else
      do nothing
```

Any help would be appreciated. Let me know if you need more info to help out.

UI tech used is WinForms.

Comment: not really a good practice.

Comment: What UI technology are you using? WinForms? WPF? UWP? It's helpful if you add the tag for that so that people can give the best advice for the given tech. Feel free to [edit] your question to do so.

Comment: @HereticMonkey The UI is WinForms sorry for that.

Comment: When you click the hyperlink on Form A, you can create the wizard, set a public property, then show the wizard.